# Current page title token doesn't change when going to multiple pages

Tags: 8, tokens

I have a block where I want to include a token of the current page Title. But it's either caching or locking up after the first page.

In a sidebar there's a block where I've tried two things:
1. "Find out more about [current-page:title]..."
2. "Find out more about [node:title]..."

[node:title] gives nothing - a blank result.

[current-page:title] will often give the first page a visitor sees. But when they navigate to another page, it only remembers the previous page. They visit page#2 and the text still says "Find out more about page#1"

I don't even know where to begin on this. I have enabled Tokens, as well as Custom tokens and Pathauto. I don't think those would cause any issues, but I mention just in case.

I can research and modify this question if someone has an idea what steps I might take to refine to something more specific

Comment: What block? A custom block created from the UI, or provided from a custom module? This block simply seems to be cached too hard when it must be cached per URL.

Comment: I agree with @leymannx, sounds like this block lacks cache context. Regular UI blocks are not meant to be used dynamically like this. I suggest you create View bock instead with contextual filter of entity id, this is the proper approach.